# how to deploy angular app to IIS and what to write in the url (for windows server)

Tags: angular, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to deploy angular app in wwwroot file
I don't know what to write in url below, I don't have the alias to write I suppose.

```
  [action type="Rewrite" url="here" /]
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try below steps to create and host the angular site in iis:

first, make sure you installed node in your machine by running below command:

```
node --version
```

install Angular CLI using npm

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

run below command and enter to the wwwroot folder:

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

Create a new Angular project

```
ng new hello-world
```

Now that the basic application is ready we’ll host the application from the console using ng serve ….

```
ng serve
```

then build the application

```
ng build
```

[image]

[image]

Once the build completes successfully it publishes all the build artifacts to the dist folder.

create a site in iis and set the folder path with dist folder:

[image]

[image]

url rewrite routing rule:

This step is required to support deep-linking. Deep-linking is the capability for the user to navigate directly to a page by typing the route into the address bar instead of using the Angular routing. Deep-linking causes a problem for IIS because the URL that the user attempts to access is not known to the server and therefore the user receives a 404 response. The solution is for the server to always return the root of the application, even if the user requests a path within the application.

We’ll now add a web.config file in which we’ll have the URL rewrite rule. All requests to this web application that are not for files or folders should be redirected to the root of the application. For an web application or virtual directory under the default web site, the URL should be set to the alias, (e.g. /MyApp/). For a web site at the root of the server, the URL should be set to /.

In our case since we are using the web application HelloWorld we’ll set the url /HelloWorld/

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/HelloWorld/" />
        <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />-->
        </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```